# composer error when running bin/magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, cli

When I try to run a `bin/magento` command, I get this error:

```
Composer file not found#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerFactory.php(47): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerJsonFinder->findComposerJson()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(368): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerFactory->create()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(381): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getComposer()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(244): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getLocker()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(122): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getSystemPackages()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(82): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getSystemPackageVersion()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion()
#7 /var/www/html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#8 {main}
```

Here is what I tried so far:

- `bin/magento clear:cache` & `bin/magento cache:flush` - gives the same error above.
- `composer install` - gives the same error above.
- `composer update` - gives `Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Users/Ismail/Development/magento2project`

How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if composer is installed and configured correctly. What happens when you run `composer --version`? If its installed, check to see if its enabled globally. Go over the steps from https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md and try again. One more thing, did you install Magento via composer or dowloaded it as a zip ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. The problem was that I had to restart my docker container.